# PDF annotation tool and management for Mac

Tags: osx, pdf, annotation

I am looking for a tool which allows me to load PDF documents, annotate & comment on them, and then "browse" the annotations and comments in some form of viewer (perhaps like a spreadsheet). The browser/viewer must show the link to the PDF, comment, highlight: 1 row per comment/highlight/URL.

Anyone know of something like this?